# How to tell if a WFS service supports `urn` identifiers for `srsName`

Tags: coordinate-system, wfs, web-mapping, getcapabilities

Specifying a `urn` for the `srsName` parameter for a WFS GetFeatures request can be better, as it can enforce a stricter structure of the returned data. E.g. If I specify `srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326` then I know that the service will return coordinates in lat, long order. If I just specify `srsName=EPSG:4326` then the coords of returned features are sometimes in long, lat order.

So we would like to specify `srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326` wherever possible!
But some WFS services do not accept the `urn` format for the `srsName` parameter.
Is there any way to determine whether this is supported from a GetCapabilities request?

I have thought to parse the GetCapabilities response and use the first option listed in a `<wfs:DefaultSRS>` or `<wfs:OtherSRS>` tag that includes "4326". If a WFS service supports urn format will this be specified in the DefaultSRS tag?

An excerpt from a GetCapabilities response for a server that does not support `urn`:

```xml
<wfs:DefaultSRS>EPSG:28355</wfs:DefaultSRS>
<wfs:OtherSRS>EPSG:7855</wfs:OtherSRS>
<wfs:OtherSRS>EPSG:4326</wfs:OtherSRS>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's WFS version 2.0.0 (https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=39967) it must support URN's for the srsName parameter.

> 7.9.2.4.4 srsName parameter
>
> Servers that implement this International Standard **shall** be able
> to process srsName attribute values using the  following format model:

`urn:ogc:def:objectType:authority:version:<EPSG code> (see OGC 07-092r2)`

> In this format model, objectType shall have the value of "crs",
> authority shall have the value "crs" and the  value  is a
> placeholder for the actual EPSG code value.